# Ответ Telegram бота из нескольких частей

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Как прописать  `bot.reply_to` содержащий текст и переменные списка?
Т.е.

```
bot.reply_to(message, "Text1", a[index], "Text2", b[index])
```

Comment: Уточни, пожалуйста, на каком языке ты пишешь?

Comment: Python. Сейчас в теги добавлю.

Answer (score 0):

Ввёл дополнительню переменную, составил из неё ответ и вставил её как аргумент bot.reply_to :

```
answer = "Text1" + str(a[index]) + "Text2" + str(b[index]))
bot.reply_to(message, answer)
```